# Socket IO + React - 'Welcome message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm planning on adding a 'Welcome' message to all users that join a chat. I can't seem to get it to work.

Server Side:

```
socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!' });
```

client side in the useEffect hook:

```
  socket.on('welcome', function(data) {
       welcomeMessage(data.message)
    })    

  function welcomeMessage(message) {
    messages([message]);
  }
```

Comment: what is `messages` in welcomeMessage function ? ... probably you need to set the updated data in your case welcome message in state of your component. are you doing that ?

Comment: I am not hmm ill try and look into it

Comment: const [welcome, setWelcome] = useState([]);  // 
  function welcomeMessage(welcome) {
    setWelcome(welcome);
  }

Comment: `setWelcome(welcome.concat(message))` what do you think about this? or may be `setWelcome([...welcome, message])`